# How can I put text in the textbox HTML helper?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I'm using the textbox HTML helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(u=>u.Something)
```

How can I show some text inside of the textbox when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply by following this form:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Something, new { @Value = "Add your value here"})
```

Comment: for razor view it will be
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Something, new { @Value = "Add your value here"})